# XPATH to get distinct set of nodes from XML

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have an XML file as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body xmlns:bons0="http://DistinctAppSample" xmlns:httpsca="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/websphere/http/sca/6.1.0" xmlns:mq="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/websphere/mq/sca/6.0.0" xmlns:smo="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/sibx/smo/v6.0.1" xmlns:tns="http://DistinctAppSample/TestInf" xmlns:tns1="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:tns2="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tns_1="wsdl.http://DistinctAppSample/TestInf" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="foo.xsd">
  <tns:testOperation>
    <input>
      <request>
        <salary>100</salary>
        <newSalary>101</newSalary>
      </request>
      <request>
        <salary>123</salary>
        <newSalary>101</newSalary>
      </request>
      <request>
        <salary>101</salary>
        <newSalary>123</newSalary>
      </request>
      <request>
        <salary>100</salary>
        <newSalary>101</newSalary>
      </request>
    </input>
  </tns:testOperation>
</body>
```

I am trying to remove the duplicate "request" node where we have same salary and newSalary value (node1 and node4 has same values. So I need to consider only one node). Sample output is follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body xmlns:bons0="http://DistinctAppSample" xmlns:httpsca="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/websphere/http/sca/6.1.0" xmlns:mq="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/websphere/mq/sca/6.0.0" xmlns:smo="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/sibx/smo/v6.0.1" xmlns:tns="http://DistinctAppSample/TestInf" xmlns:tns1="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:tns2="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tns_1="wsdl.http://DistinctAppSample/TestInf" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="foo.xsd">
  <tns:testOperation>
    <input>
      <request>
        <salary>100</salary>
        <newSalary>101</newSalary>
      </request>
      <request>
        <salary>123</salary>
        <newSalary>101</newSalary>
      </request>
      <request>
        <salary>101</salary>
        <newSalary>123</newSalary>
      </request>     
    </input>
  </tns:testOperation>
</body>
```

I would need to write a XPATH to achieve this Scenario.
I have tried `//request[not(salary = preceding::salary and newSalary = preceding::newSalary)]` but it is not working as expected. Any suggesition would be much appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: XPath is a selection language. It cannot change your XML. Do you want to select certain nodes or do you want to create a new XML document?

Comment: I would like to create a new XML document. Select the XML nodes using XPATH and create a new XML file.

Comment: Ah, from your tags I see that you're prepared to use XSLT, that's probably the best tool for the job. Search for examples using `<xsl:for-each-group>`, try to adapt them. When you have some XSLT to show, show it.

Comment: Actually, I cannot use XSLT directly. I have a UI to do mapping from Input node to Output node and internally a XSL file will be generated. In UI, i did not find anything realted to <xsl:for-each-group>. Therefore trying to do with XPATH.

Comment: As I said initially, XPath cannot be used for producing a new XML file from an old one. It's a query language, not a document creation language. If the XSLT is generated by a tool, you need to be specific about the tool.

Comment: On second thought, try `//request[not(salary = preceding-sibling::request/salary and newSalary = preceding-sibling::request/newSalary)]`. Might work with your mapping tool.

Comment: Tool is IBM Integration Designer. I am aware that XPath cannot be used for producing the new XML file. But with that XPATH I can select the only unique nodes. After selecting the nodes, i would convert the result to a XML  - may be usinga java program. My request is to select the unique XML nodes from the file.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks for your inputs. It worked with the above xpath.